# Convergence in probabiliy uniformly in x- continuous mapping theorem?

Tags: probability

Suppose a sequence of random variables $X_n \stackrel{\mathbb{P}}\longrightarrow X$. Then the continuous mapping theorem tells us that $g(X_n)\stackrel{\mathbb{P}}\longrightarrow g(X)$, if g is continuous.

Now, g is a function in two parameters, $g(X_n,x)$, with $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Do I have a stament like $g(X_n,x)\stackrel{\mathbb{P}}\longrightarrow g(X,x)$ uniformly with respect to $x$, if my function $g$ ist continuous in **both** parameters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work uniformly in $x$. Consider $X_n = \frac{1}{n}$, $X = 0$ and $g(x, y) = xy$. Then clearly $\|g(X_n, x) - g(X, x)\|_\infty = \infty$ does not converge in probability to $0$.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that's convincing. But how is the situation, if I take $x\in K\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $K$ is a compact set?

Comment: Or if we assume $g$ to be uniformly continuous in x? I guess then it will work...?